# WeChat Mini-program: How to print log to console?

Tags: wechat

I'm trying to print variable in the console, For this I have the configuration below. the first method works fine, but not the second method containing an argument.

In `index.wxml` file, I have:

```
<button onclick='test1'>Button 1</button>
<button onclick='test2("bar")'>Button 1</button>
```

In `index.js`, I have:

```
Page({
  test1 {
    console.log('foo')
  },
  test2(v) {
    console.log('foo: ' + v)
  },
})
```

What's wrong with the second method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it's been a while since you asked this question and maybe you don't need an answer anymore, but I ran into this problem too, so probably others will too.

`Page` is a function that takes a json object as input. So you should rewrite `index.js` like this:

```js
Page({
  test1 : function() {
    console.log('foo')
  },
  test2 : function(v) {
    console.log('foo: ' + v)
  },
})
```

The documentation for the `Page` class is hard to find, and as far as I can tell, they haven't translated it. It exists [here](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/reference/api/Page.html) in Chinese.

Even though those are technically anonymous functions, you can use the keys of the json object in your wxml file as if they were functions. Your wxml file is basically right, but I'm not sure that `onclick` actually works. Try `bindtap` or `bindchange`.

[This page](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/framework/view/wxml/event.html) has Tencent's english documentation of how to handle events in the WXML. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Dear Guys.In wechat mini program,if you want to pass arguments to a function,you should do it like in the following way,for examples
Firstyly,you write your tap events in your index.wxml

```
<view bindtap="handleTap" data-item="100"> passing arguments through events</view>
```

Then you can define a function call handleTap in your index.js file,like

```
   handleTap:function(e){
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.item); 
   }
```

Now when you click,you can see the value log in the console,wechat mini programming passes arguments through the attribute "data-*".